# Estimation of the shape parameter of gamma distribution in Winbugs

Tags: estimation, gamma-distribution, bugs

I want to estimate the shape parameter of gamma distribution in Winbugs.
I select gamma distribution as prior for shape parameter.
Data set is generated using MATLAB as:

```
gamrnd(5,1,[100 1])
```

a  small part of data loaded to model is here:

```
list(n=100,b=1)
y[,1]
9.85509822926424
6.78794280129914
2.37341388433267
5.44664020179438
14.7723695566505
4.53177357981821
.
.
END
```

The model in Winbugs is simple and as follows:

```
model;
{
   for( i in 1 : n ) {
      y[i] ~ dgamma(a,b)
   }
   a ~ dgamma(3,1)
}
```

Estimation is strongly dependent on the prior that was selected for **a**.
As for each distribution, (normal-gamma-uniform) the estimated **a** value is around the mean value of the selected prior distribution.
For example, choosing the above-mentioned prior (**a ~ dgamma(3,1)**) resulted in shape parameter estimation 3.026; also running the model for more iterations doesn't change results so much!

What is the problem and how can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run a similar script in R, but it seems that OK, setting prior of the b

How is your prior of b setting?

Has your MCMC chain already converged?

PS: I tried something as below as you set b as fixed.
But I also tried some other prior of b, it is OK.

```
N <- 100
x <- rgamma(N, 5, 1)


write("
model {
    for (i in 1:length(x)) {
        x[i] ~ dgamma(a, b)
    }
    a ~ dgamma(3, 1)
    b <- 1
}",
file="example1.bug")

jags <- jags.model('example1.bug',
                   data = list('x' = x),
                   n.chains = 4,
                   n.adapt = 100)


mcmc.samples <- coda.samples(jags,
             c('a', "b"),
             n.iter = 10000) 

summary(mcmc.samples)
```

Comment: yes coverage is occurred! i supposed **b** to be constant and the data set is added to question.

Comment: may i ask you for the R script for this model?

Comment: @user110502 it seems that other b's prior like log-normal I tried is also OK. But you could try the script above.

Comment: @user110502 Note that asking for code (arguably) takes this off-topic. Your original question floats somewhere between statistics and statistical computing, but the help for CV does spell out that questions focused entirely on code belong elsewhere.